# How can i create n columns in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, function, multiple-columns

I am trying to write a function that returns random start time (it must be between now and a week long) and an endtime. I wrote this function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION random_start_end_time(n integer)
RETURNS TABLE (startime TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE, endtime TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE)
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS $BODY$
BEGIN
RETURN QUERY

SELECT NOW() + (random() * (NOW()+'7 days' - NOW())) as startime; 
SELECT NOW() + (random() * (NOW()+'7 days' - NOW())) as endtime;

END;
$BODY$
```

I can't find out how to generate multiple columns. For example I want n=100 columns of random start time and end time to be generated.

In general I can't understand how I can fill an empty table (with this function I am going to fill a table later).

Any thoughts would be valuable.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure you're looking for multiple columns (other times than start and end), not multiple rows?

Answer (score 0):

Use `RETURN NEXT` to add a row to the result set of a table function and `RETURN` to end the function execution.  You also have to decide if you want a function that returns two columns or two rows.  Your case looks like you want to do something like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION random_start_end_time(
   OUT starttime TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE,
   OUT endtime TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE
) RETURNS record
   LANGUAGE sql AS
$BODY$
WITH start AS (
   SELECT current_timestamp + random() * INTERVAL '7 days' as starttime
)
SELECT starttime,
       starttime + random() * INTERVAL '7 days' as endtime
FROM start;
$BODY$;
```

Call it like

```
SELECT * FROM random_start_end_time();
```

If you really want to return several rows, that would be

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION random_start_end_time()
   RETURNS SETOF timestamp with time zone
   LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
   RETURN NEXT current_timestamp + random() * INTERVAL '7 days';
   RETURN NEXT current_timestamp + random() * INTERVAL '7 days';
   RETURN;  /* end the function */
END;
$BODY$;
```

Comment: Thank you for your response .The function doesnt work for me as i get this message :column "starttime" does not exist.The real question is how can i generate mutiple rows of startimes and endtimes in order to fill a table later?

Comment: I have fixed the answer, sorry for the errors.